# Why the top right corner of my table is open?

Tags: tables

Why the top right corner of my table is open? [image]
I have attached the picture of the table and my overleaf code for generating this table is:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\label{T:equipos}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\thead{\textbf{Model} \\ \textbf{No.}} & \multicolumn{6}{ c |}{\textbf{Fault No.}}  \\ 
\cline{2-7}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline

1 & & &  &  & & \\ \hline
2 & &  &   &   & & \\ \hline
3 & & &  &  & & \\ \hline
4 & & &  &  & & \\ \hline
5 & & &   &  & & \\ \hline
6 & & &  & & & \\ \hline
7 & & &   &   & & \\ \hline
8 & & &   &   & & \\ \hline
9 & & &   &   & & \\ \hline
10 & &  &   &   & & \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate the screenshot you posted when using the code you show. (In order to make your code fragment compilable, I had to prefix `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{makecell} \begin{document}` and affix `\end{document}`.) Please tell us more about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ, and with which options do load the `makecell` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing your code and compiling, I had no such problem. I post the code I used to have a better layout, using `multirow` for the 1st column head, and removing the `center` environment, which adds a spurious vertical spacing, in favour of the `\centering` directive.

*Edit*: as mentioned by @Mico, `\label` won't do anything, unless you have a `\caption` command before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\label{T:equipos}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multirowthead{2}{Model \\[-0.5ex] No. } & \multicolumn{6}{ c |}{\textbf{Fault No.}} \\
\cline{2-7}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline

1 & & & & & & \\ \hline
2 & & & & & & \\ \hline
3 & & & & & & \\ \hline
4 & & & & & & \\ \hline
5 & & & & & & \\ \hline
6 & & & & & & \\ \hline
7 & & & & & & \\ \hline
8 & & & & & & \\ \hline
9 & & & & & & \\ \hline
10 & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may also want to mention the fact that the directive `\label{T:equipos}` won't do anything useful unless one precedes it with a `\caption` instruction.

Comment: Oh! yes. I mainly focused on the look of the table, and forgot this problem. I'll add it instantly. Thanks!